# Get Information from a selected bar - dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I create charts with crossfilter and dc.js.

In Chart Nr.1 you can see how many guests visit a resturant per day, and the second chart shows the age of the guests. Both are bar charts.

For some calculations I need information from the selected bar. For Example:

In Chart Nr.1 you select the date 16/03/2019 and you see in Chart Nr.2 100 Guests were older then 50 and 30 younger then 50.

Now I need a variable with the 100 Guests, and another with the 30 Guests.

How I get at the data behind the aggregated value of each bar?

Comment: I started to answer this but I think it's better to link to [a reductio function that does this](https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#aggregations-standard-aggregations-reductio-data-list) or a [relevant dc.js example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/complex-reduce.html) rather than write new code for a well-known pattern. As noted below, it's not efficient and [in some cases it might be better just to nest the data from scratch](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1497) since crossfilter is best for incremental aggregations rather than fetching all the rows.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer. I will try it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

You could override the bar charts onClick function to save the value selected:

```
var valueSelected;

dc.override(barChart, 'render', function () {

    barChart.selectAll('rect').on("click", function (d) {
        valueSelected = d.data.value;

        //call original onClick:
        barChart.onClick(d);
    });

    barChart.selectAll('text.barLabel').on("click", function (d) {
        valueSelected = d.data.value;

        //call original onClick:
        barChart.onClick(d);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think the question is how to retrieve all the individual rows, not how to get the aggregated sum. It's a bit more difficult and crossfilter doesn't directly support it because it's not an efficient operation.